# Getting stuck with phoenix app running as systemd Services

Tags: ubuntu, elixir, phoenix-framework, systemd

I want my phoenix app run as a systemd service on Ubuntu16.04, I create a file in /lib/systemd/system/myapp.service, and enable it by: `systemctl enable myapp.service`. after doing this, I can't start the application by `systemctl start myapp.service`, it print nothing. When I run `systemctl status myapp.server`, it shows inactive. Here is my myapp.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=my server
After=network.target
After=syslog.target

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=myapp.service

[Service]
# Start main service
Type=simple
ExecStart=/var/www/server/bCareServer/bin/myapp start
ExecReload=/var/www/server/bCareServer/bin/myapp restart
Restart=on-failure
PrivateTmp=false
```

Here is the output of  `systemctl status myapp.service`:

```
xxx:/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants# systemctl status myapp.service
● myapp.service - my server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/myapp.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2017-04-06 17:41:17 CST; 3s ago
Process: 29687      ExecStart=/var/www/server/bCareServer/bin/myapp start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 29687 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

 Apr 06 17:41:17 xxx systemd[1]: Started my server.
```

I can still manually start the app by type: `/var/www/server/bCareServer/bin/myapp start`.

Comment: Can you post the complete output of `systemctl status myapp.service`? There should be some error logged if it failed to start with `systemctl start ...`.

Comment: I'd recommend running using the foreground command under systemd, the second approach from the distillery guide https://hexdocs.pm/distillery/use-with-systemd.html#content - it never failed me.

Comment: @Veetase please add it to the question. There's no output in your comment and you cannot post long text in comments anyways.

Comment: @michalmuskala After comparing with your guide, I finally find that I missed to set the `Environment=PORT=80`. I have set the system environment variable, so I don't know why it is necessary.